# Laravel - using ID's to represent values in another table

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have two tables for my vehicles website:

I have a table in my DB which contains all car makes:

```
ID | name | display_name

1  | audi | Audi
2  | bmw  | BMW
```

I also have a vehicles table:

```
ID | VRM     | make

1  | HW55VRM | 2
2  | VN62HHS | 1
```

When editing a vehicle this is the method for creating the view:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $vehicle = $this->vehicle->getSingle($id);
    $makes = $this->vehicle->getMakes();
    $models = $this->vehicle->getModels();
    return View::make('admin.vehicles.edit', compact('makes', 'models', 'vehicle'));
}
```

On this view I have a select box:

```
{{ Form::select('make',$models , NULL, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Which correctly creates a select box with the options I need. However, I want to set one of these values as selected depending on the table row data.

So the first vehicle in my DB has '2' as its make. Which represents a BMW.

How can I add that to my $vehicles variable in the cleanest way? So I can just do

```
$vehicle->named_make
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Eloquent models then provided you have proper relationships defined you can do like that

```
$vehicle->make->display_name
```